# Files added to documents directory shows up in Simulator but nothing in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

This is the code I'm using and it works in simulator but showing nothing in idevice. If I add an folder or a file through ifunbox it shows up in device though. Do I need any permission to create or add files?

```
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"/Folders/%@", self.txtFolder.text]];
    NSLog(@"%@", dataPath);

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder

        [sec1Contents addObject:self.txtFolder.text];
        sec1 = [NSArray arrayWithArray:sec1Contents];
        [self.tblFiles reloadData];
    }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: how you are seeing it in iphone?

Comment: have you copied the file in appdelegate?

Comment: @amar sorry but which file?

Comment: @VaibhavSaran Documents folder is empty.

Comment: I have updated the answer please follow

Comment: sometimes I do a stupid thing. Running app on device and looking for its files inside Simulator's Document folder. Make sure you are not doing this ;). Files of device will appear inside device's document folder, not in iOS simulator's document folder. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Use this code :    

NSURL *allitemsImageurl =[NSURL URLWithString: url];
    NSData *allItemsImageData = data1;  // Load XML data from web
    NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString * documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *st1=[ @"img_" stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",imageCount]];

    NSString *allitemsImagePath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:st1];
    NSLog(@"%@",allitemsImagePath);
    [allItemsImageData writeToFile:allitemsImagePath atomically:TRUE];
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. It seems something was wrong with my device.